# Issue with getting control id when tabcontainer is used

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I have an AJAX Control Toolkit `TabContainer` in my ASP.NET page. In one of the tabs in the `TabContainer`, there is a `GridView`. Now, I have an `UpdatePanel` for which I want to give trigger as "RowCommand" of `GridView` mentioned above. The `UpdatePanel` is outside the `TabContainer`. But when I give the `GridView` id, I am getting the error:

> A control with ID 'grvSummary' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'updSegment'.

Trigger markup:

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="grvSummary" EventName="RowCommand" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to programmatically add the trigger to your `UpdatePanel`.  This is because your GridView may or may not start in a different `ContentPlaceHolder` than the `UpdatePanel` (namely, the `<ContentTemplate>` of your `TabContainer`).  Like this (note that this really needs to be done in `Page_Init`, due to the [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)):

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AsyncPostBackTrigger trig = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
    trig.ControlID = grvSummary.UniqueID;
    trig.EventName = "RowCommand";
    updSegment.Triggers.Add(trig);
}
```

It looks like this may be a problem with ASP.NET / AJAX assuming the wrong `Control.UniqueID` value for the `Control` being used as a trigger.

Source: [Triggering an UpdatePanel in a different ContentPlaceHolder](http://weblogs.asp.net/pauljuenger/archive/2008/10/10/triggering-an-update-panel-from-a-control-in-a-different-contentplaceholder.aspx)